# Разбор входной строки

Tags: алгоритм, php

В переменной такое значение:

```
1;2;3;4;5;6;
```

Т.е. элементы разделены через точку с запятой. Мне нужно, чтобы эти элементы записались в  соответствующею ячейку массива. Кто можете помочь с реализацией?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$var = '1;2;3;4;5;6';
$row = explode(';', $var);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($row);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: faic palm, в `explode` сначала разделитель передается а не переменная...

Comment: explode там значения только местами поменять и впринцепе все работает, спс =)

Comment: да но афтар ответа поменять неудосужился...

Comment: не важно =) и еще вопросик а как определить длинну $row можно? ну т.е. посчитать сколько в нем эл-ов получилось?

Comment: count($row);

Comment: все, всем спс, можно закрывать =)

Answer (score 3):

стыдно вам должно быть за такие вопросы..

хоть попытались бы поискать ответ в нете..

http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php - для работы с строками

http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php - для работы с масивами